# how can i change header and footer different for even and odd pages and different for front page

Tags: formatting

how can we change header and footer different for first page and after that from second page we need to apply odd and even pages header and footer. like on front page we want image and name of our university. while from 2nd page on even pages we want authors name and on odd pages we want title of document

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far? Did your university provide templates? Checked them? Which documentclass do you use?  Please explain better what the exact problem is you have ... Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: The `fancyhdr` package might answer your question.